# SQL query syntax to retrieve data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in Mysql: `authors` and `articles`.

I have authors with several articles for each of them.

I need sql query  with the result of this query:
retrieve 3 authors ordered by age with all articles which belong each of them.

In my example it will be

```
ID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    AGE AUTHORID    TITLE       PRICE
6   Salido      Gomes       90  6           All 3       1
6   Salido      Gomes       90  6           All 3       33
6   Salido      Gomes       90  6           All 3       3
5   Vitora      Mantora     45  5           Total 3     99
5   Vitora      Mantora     45  5           Total 3     33
5   Vitora      Mantora     45  5           Total 3     12
3   Joe         Smith       43  3           Python      5
3   Joe         Smith       43  3           Python 2    22
3   Joe         Smith       43  3           Python 3    44
3   Joe         Smith       43  3           Python 4    12
3   Joe         Smith       43  3           Python 5    67
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/718c4/1

I use

```
select * from authors join articles on authors.id = articles.authorId
join (select authors.id from authors order by age DESC limit 3) as t
on t.id = authors.id
```

with wrong result

```
ID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    AGE AUTHORID    TITLE   PRICE
6   Salido      Gomes       90  6           All 3   1
6   Salido      Gomes       90  6           All 3   33
6   Salido      Gomes       90  6           All 3   3
```

Comment: The problem here is that of your 3 oldest authors, 2 have not written any articles in the test data you have provided (ID 7 and 8) in the sql fiddle. Hence just the details of a single author are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to include authors who have written any articles in the top 3 oldest authors try doing a join between authors and articles in the sub query to get the 3 oldest authors, and DISTINCT to eliminate duplicates:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT authors.id, authors.firstname, authors.lastname, authors.age
    FROM authors 
    JOIN articles 
    ON authors.id = articles.authorId
    ORDER BY authors.age 
    DESC 
    LIMIT 3
) author_sub
JOIN articles 
ON author_sub.id = articles.authorId
```